# Що впливає на помилкове слововживання виясняти питання?

Tags: словосполучення, стилістика

Знаємо, що **виясняти питання** ― [НЕ правильно](http://nepravylno-pravylno.wikidot.com/all):

> **Вияснення** всіх питань ― **З'ясування** всіх питань

Однак, в [СУМі](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=11885&page=394) знаходимо це слово у значенні **з'ясовувати**:

> **ВИЯСНЯ́ТИ**, я́ю, я́єш, ВИЯ́СНЮВАТИ, юю, юєш, недок., ВИ́ЯСНИТИ, ню, ниш, док.
>
> 3. що. Робити що-небудь ясним, зрозумілим; *з'ясовувати*. – Я не нехтую боротьби з філоксерою, а тільки вияснюю причину ворожнечі молдуван (М. Коцюбинський); Соколова викликала головного інженера і разом з Крайнєвим і Валенсом почала виясняти строки .. подачі перших рисунків крейсера (В. Собко); Віктор пішов туди [до поранених] вияснити, що діється, навести порядок (Л. Дмитерко).

Чому тоді вислів **виясняти питання** не правильно вживати в українській мові?